# Regex split on comma except on escaping with double comma (Java, Scala)

Tags: java, regex, scala, split

Could anyone help me with a regular expression in java/scala to split a string on commas but not when escaped by a comma.

For example:

`"value1,value2,value3" -> ["value1","value2","value3"]`

`"value1,,6,value2,value3" -> ["value1,,6","value2","value3"]`

Here comma is used both as a delimiter and to escape the delimiter.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What did you try so far? What didn't work?

Comment: Not a good idea to use split for this.

Comment: This should work, where group 1 contains contents of the quoted field, or group 2 contains the contents of a non-quoted field. `"(?m)(?:(?:^|\s*,)\s*)(?:\"([^\"\\]*(?:(?:\\[\S\s]|\"\")[^\"\\]*?)*)\"|([^,\r\n]*?))(?:\s*(?=$|,))"`

https://regex101.com/r/lsZbo7/1 And fwiw, once inside a quoted field, the delimiter `,` or anything other than an escaped quote is just a character, not a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `((?<!,),(?!(,{2})*+,))`. It matches any `,`, that does not immediately follow a comma, and is not immediately followed by a comma (or an odd number of commas).

```java
for(String a : "value1,,6,value2,value3,,,val4,,,,val5".split("((?<!,),(?!(,{2})*+,))")) {
    System.out.println(a.replaceAll(",,", ","));
}
```

Outpup:

```
value1,6
value2
value3
,val4,,val5
,,val6
```

Also, split string still contains "escaped" commas, hence `.replaceAll(",,", ",")`.